# Convert duration in XXm, YYs format to time value

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, time, parsing

In Microsot Excel, I have string data that represents duration of an event:

| duration |
| --- |
| 40s |
| 5m, 40s |
| 59m, 59s |

I need to convert the values to time (in adjacent column) so that I can format and sort the data properly. For example:

| duration | seconds | formatted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40s | 40 | 00:00:40 |
| 5m, 40s | 340 | 00:05:40 |
| 59m, 59s | 3599 | 00:59:59 |

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I think `{0,60,1}` should be `{3600,60,1}` if you want to include hours.

Comment: Yes sorry I missed it! I will update in answers. Removed the comment since there was a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternative options, you could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MID("0"&A2,SEARCH({"d","h","m","s"},A2)-1,2),0)*{"1","1:0","0:1","0:0:1"})*86400
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MID(0&A2,SEARCH({"d","h","m","s"},0&A2)-2,2),{0,0,0,0})*{86400,3600,60,1})
```

---

And in <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=B2/24/60/60
```

---

Format cells as `[h]:mm:ss;@`

---

Comment: Sorry, it is not working in Excel 2016

Comment: Those solutions works from `Excel 2010+` onwards.

Comment: All I get is zeros: https://i.stack.imgur.com/88XGf.png

Comment: Please download to see oñ your end, probably you going to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode. **[Download](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckFE_BTtnxXFU680a?e=1sUIQw)**

Comment: @SalmanA also change `SUM()` to `SUMPRODUCT()`

Comment: `sumproduct` it was

Comment: @SalmanA Sir glad to know it worked on your end!